# How to make flex row responsive Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

Currently the page looks like this:

[image]

Now on resize to mobile screen flex boxes overflow the container:

[image]

Html:

```
       <div id="bars" class="d-flex flex-row text-white  text-center">
            <div class="port-item p-4 bg-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#home">
                <i class="fa fa-home d-block"></i> Home
            </div>
            <div class="port-item p-4 bg-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#resume">
                 <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap d-block"></i> Resume
            </div>
            <div class="port-item p-4 bg-warning" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#work">
                 <i class="fa fa-folder-open d-block"></i> Work
            </div>
            <div class="port-item p-4 bg-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#contact">
            <i class="fa fa-envelope d-block"></i> Contact
            </div>
            </div>
```

CSS, I tried with media but nothig has changed

```
.port-item {
width: 30%;
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  #bars {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

How can I make them fit to container or to make them to display on column

Comment: have you check the docs ? https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#responsive-classes to start with ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `min-width` is `auto` for a *flex item* in a *flexbox* - so add `min-width: 0` to `port-item` to reset it.

Now the boxes will not overflow the container. Also you can use media queries to set the column flow in smaller devices:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #bars {
    flex-direction: column !important;
  }
  .port-item {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

See demo below:

```css
.port-item {
  width: 30%;
  min-width: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #bars {
    flex-direction: column !important;
  }
  .port-item {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="bars" class="d-flex flex-row text-white  text-center">
  <div class="port-item p-4 bg-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#home">
    <i class="fa fa-home d-block"></i> Home
  </div>
  <div class="port-item p-4 bg-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#resume">
    <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap d-block"></i> Resume
  </div>
  <div class="port-item p-4 bg-warning" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#work">
    <i class="fa fa-folder-open d-block"></i> Work
  </div>
  <div class="port-item p-4 bg-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#contact">
    <i class="fa fa-envelope d-block"></i> Contact
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 16):

Not sure you need to use CSS to sort this as the Bootstrap classes should cover this.

Replace your flex class "d-flex flex-row" with "d-flex flex-column d-sm-flex flex-sm-row"

and your 4 items will auto stack on mobile and go side by side above that

Comment: Absolutely: Use the bootstrap utility classes - thats what they're there for. And they'll work when/if the breakpoints were to change later. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

i made that For you :) :)

```
<div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-xl-row justify-content-xl-between flex-column">

<div class="bloc_1 p-2" style="background-color: red"> picture </div>

<div class="bloc_2 p-2" style="background-color: antiquewhite">
 <div class="d-flex flex-column">
     <div class="p-4"> Headline</div>
     <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between">
         <div> Flex 1</div>
         <div> Flex 2</div>
         <div> Flex 3</div>
         <div> Flex 4</div>
     </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

the initial state :

[image: the initial state]

after resize :

[image]

==> you can read the Doc of the Flex for more info ..

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/